# extract data from a ". dat" file and form a 9x4 matrix

Tags: r

I want to extract a matrix data from THREE ".dat" files with file names x1,x2 and x3 and combine them in one matrix.  ( I have merged them here for convenience but should be assumed from three files). Each file has 3x3 matrix data. I want to extract the data in each file with corresponding DATE on one column. So the result will have 4 columns and 9 rows. The date should be written on the first row of each matrix and the rest of the spaces can be filled with NA's or leave them. Here is the file:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkgkD.png)

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (pictures of data are not helpful). Describe where exactly you are having trouble (we're not here just to write code for you). Show the code you have attempted to write to solve the problem.

Comment: Do not use images.  Use text so readers can copy and paste them.  Also show expected output and show the code of your attempted solution.

Comment: Try `files <- list.files(); lst <- lapply(files, read.csv, skip=3, header=FALSE); lst2 <- lapply(files, scan, skip=2, nlines=1); Datetime <- sub(".*:\\s+", "", unlist(lst2)); do.call(rbind, Map(`cbind`, lst, Datetime=Datetime))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the files have 3 header lines before the beginning of data and if all the files are in the working directory.  Get all the files from the working directory using `list.files()`.  Loop through the 'files', read the dataset with `read.csv`, `skip` the first 3 lines, specifying the `header` as FALSE.  Then, we third line from each of the files with `scan`, remove the substring until the date part with `sub`, create a column in each of the `list` element using `Map`, and `rbind` the output to have a single data.frame.

```
files <- list.files()
lst <- lapply(files, read.csv, skip=3, header=FALSE)
lst2 <- lapply(files, scan, skip=2, nlines=1, what = "")
Datetime <- sub(".*:\\s+", "", unlist(lst2))
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lst, Datetime=Datetime))
```